# Copying only values and not the formulas using copy destination code in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to copy the cells that are left in the filtered table, but only copy their values not formulas.  I used the code below which works fine unless the filter only leaves one row in which I get the error:

> script out of range

for the `[Sheets("Cost Accounting").Range(A2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues]` code line.

I attached an image of an example where the code will not paste (when there is only a single row left after the filter)
[image: Example Problem Scenario]

```
Sub DT_test()

    Dim table As ListObject
    Dim rngToCopy As Range

    Sheets.Add.Name = ("Cost Accounting")
    Sheets("Cost Accounting").Activate
    
    TeamRole2 = "Cost Accounting"
    MaxDate = Date
    
    Set table = Worksheets("Overview").ListObjects("Table1")
    
    table.Range.AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:=TeamRole2
    table.Range.AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:="<" & MaxDate
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Set rngToCopy = table.DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If Not rngToCopy Is Nothing Then
        rngToCopy.Copy
        Sheets("Cost Accounting").Range(A2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End If

    table.Range.AutoFilter

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try pasting the values...

```
If Not rngToCopy Is Nothing Then
    rngToCopy.Copy 
    Sheets("Cost Accounting").Range("A2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End If
```

Comment: It works except for if these is only 1 row to copy after it has been filtered, then it says "Script out of range" for the pastespecial code line

Comment: Then there is no `Sheet` called `Cost Accounting`.  `Subscript out of Range` means something doesn't exist.

Comment: If you are basing "not working" on the edited code above, you left the quotes out of `Range("A2")`.